# how to filter fk related objects on django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I want to query the books that an specific person has lend currently.
I use this query `Book.objects.filter(lends__person__username__iexact="Antony")` but it's not working properly.

what i want to get is:

- the books with their latest person username who lend. (not the persons whom lend before the latest)

here is my models

```
class Person(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Lends(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(
        "Book", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="lends"
    )
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        "Person", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="lends"
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for temporal information. I recommend you add a field called created_at to the Lends class. This attribute will be populated automatically every time an object is created. By doing it you can sort in descending order.

```
class Lends(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(
        "Book", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="lends"
    )
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        "Person", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="lends"
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

So, right now you can filter and order the queryset.

```
last_lend = Lends.objects.filter(lends__person__username__iexact="Antony").order_by("-created_at").first()
```

You can see how ordering works here: [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/options/#:~:text=initial%20migrate.-,ordering,-%C2%B6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/options/#:%7E:text=initial%20migrate.-,ordering,-%C2%B6)

Answer (score 2):

> what i want to get is: 
>  the books with their latest person username who lend. (not the persons whom lend before the latest)

it can be done by using [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

latest_lended_person = Lend.objects.filter(
    book=OuterRef('pk')
).order_by('-pk')

books = Book.objects.annotate(
    latest_lended_person_username=Subquery(
        latest_lended_person.values('username')[:1]
    )
)
```